# Can Matlab fmincon take a data-structure as input instead of a vector?

Tags: matlab, optimization, input, data-structures

While trying to learn how to use Matlab's function `fmincon`, I am wondering: **is it possible to use data-structures as inputs (for the design variables and boundaries) instead of vectors?**

Here's some background details for clarification: I have a number of optimization variables (`WingWeight`, `FuelWeight`, ...). Instead of storing them in a vectors:

```
 X(1) = FuelWeight
 X(2) = WingWeight
 ...
 Xub(1) = FuelWeightub
 Xub(2) = WingWeightub
 ...
 Xlb(1) = FuelWeightlb
 Xlb(2) = WingWeightlb
 ...
```

I would like to store them in a data structure:

```
 X.WingWeight
 X.FuelWeight
 Xub.FuelWeightub
 Xub.WingWeightub
 Xlb.FuelWeightlb
 Xlb.WingWeightlb
```

My overall questions is, **will `fmincon` allow for data-structures as inputs?**

I would really like to use structures because the calculation and optimization assignment is really complex and it will take me quite a while to fully understand all the computations needed (I would have to re-edit the design vector many times and that seems really really time consuming to edit all elements everywhere in the code).

Comment: This option is discussed right in the [documentation for `fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#input_argument_problem). Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Horchler. I did not find anything on that link though; it talks about the structure of the function itself but it does not mention whether the inputs can be data structures

Comment: Please read again. I linked directly to the part of the documentation (very end of "Input Arguments" section) that discusses using a `problem` structure to specify inputs via a `struct`.

Comment: @horchler OP isn't talking about the problem structure. He want's to know if it is possible to pass an initial value `x0` as struct and get an optimized struct from fmincon back. As far as I know it is not possible. Just to pass an array as design variable that contains multiple vectors that "should be optimized for".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the current version of Matlab.